# Lazy loading messes up DI on angular

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-di

I have a module A that is a npm package that I need to use on module B that is also an npm package that is used on an app.

Module B is lazy loaded by the app.

So I have the following service on module A:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeHandlerService {
    private readonly handlers: HandlerService[] = [];
    constructor() {
        console.log('SomeHandlerService instanciated');
    }

    addHandler(handler: HandlerService): void{
        console.log(`handler count ${this.handlers.length}`);
        console.log(`some? ${this.handlers.some(h => typeof(h) === typeof(handler))}`);
        if(!this.handlers.some(h => typeof(h) === typeof(handler))){
            this.handlers.push(handler);
        }
    }

    runeHandlerLogic (someParam: paramType): Observable<boolean>{
        console.log(`handler count ${this.handlers.length}`);
        const containsHandlers = this.handlers.length > 0;
        if(!containsHandlers){
            return of(false);
        }

        

        return some logic that run handlers
    }

}
```

Then I register a handler in SomeHandlerService in my other module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        myModule
    ],
    other module DI
})
export class ModuleB{
    constructor(
        private myCustomHandler: CustomHandler,
        private someHandlerService: SomeHandlerService,
    ){
        console.log('add handler');
        console.log('handler service');
        console.log(someHandlerService);
        someHandlerService.addHandler(myCustomHandler);
    }
}
```

Then when my service in the app use the someHandlerService.runeHandlerLogic function the handler count from the console log is always 0. But when I get console log from the add method it is at 1. So there are clearly 2 instances there that are called seperately.

Not sure how to resolve that. Any tips will be appreciated.

Edit
There is how the SomeHanlderService is used.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
       private someHandlerService: SomeHandlerService
    ) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        

        return this.someHandlerService.runHandlerLogic(someParam: paramType).pipe(doSomeLogic);
    }
}
```

Comment: please also show the code where you call `runeHandlerLogic`. Is this in the same module? in the same Component? in another module? do you see the console.log "'SomeHandlerService instanciated'" twice?

Comment: It is called in an interceptor injected in the app. I will edit my question

Comment: I did edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this should always work:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
```

In my case it wasn't working because I installed my custom npm package directly from the dist folder

```
npm install C:\mylocalpackagesource\dist
```

But I had to install it from the tgz file

```
npm install C:\mylocalpackagesource\dist\mypackage.tgz
```

However I still don't know why installing it directly from the dist folder mess angular dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

not sure, but maybe your problem could be the Interceptor and not the fact that it's from other modules or lazy-loaded.
make sure to pass SomeHandlerService as deps in AppModule

```js
{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: SomeInterceptor,
    multi: true,
    deps: [SomeHandlerService]
}
```

Comment: I will look into that but the SomeHandlerService is instanciated multiple times

Comment: It is definitely not that. it really seems to have something to do with lazy loaded module